# Eclipse Tomcat Plugin - Getting Tomcat 7

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, tomcat7

I want to update my Eclipse so that I can associate projects with Tomcat 7. Currently, when I go to Window > Preferences > Tomcat, I get the following.

[image]

I originally thought it was a Eclipse version issue and I'd have to update. But I have Indigo and a friend of mine has Helios (older) and he has the Tomcat 7 option.

Then I thought the Tomcat feature might have been a plugin. So I tried Help > Check for Updates, but there were no updates.

Does anyone know how to get Version 7.x to appear?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally figured it out.

1. Close Eclipse.
2. Go [here](http://www.eclipsetotale.com/tomcatPlugin.html) and download the latest zip file to get the plugin. Inside will be a folder called com.sysdeo.eclipse.tomcat_v.v.v (v.v.v depends on which zip version you downloaded).
3. Look inside your eclipse/plugins folder and delete the old com.sysdeo.eclipse.tomcat_v.v.v file.
4. Copy the new com.sysdeo.eclipse.tomcat_v.v.v file (from the zip) into the eclipse/plugins folder.
5. Restart Eclipse.

And there you go :)